# Java User Interface: add simple chart

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, charts, charts4j

I am new to Java User Interface ..
I have my main window with a TabbedPane ...
I want to use a library of graphics to display ... I have chosen [this](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) and i looked this example ...

[ChartExample](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/source/browse/tags/v1.2/example/com/googlecode/charts4j/LineChartExample.java#116)

but, how can I add the example chart on my TabbedPane?

Comment: I don't know of `charts4j`, but if you are not limited to that library, take a look at JFreeChart - http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/index.html.

Answer (score 4):

The chart API you have chosen generates charts using Google's API. This means you'll have to display the image from the URL of `chart.toURLString();` in your app. This could be as simple as putting a `JLabel` on your tabbed pane and setting its caption to `<img src="(url)"/>`, but I'm not entirely sure that handles HTTP downloads.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<img src='" + chart.toURLString() + "'/>");
tabbedPane.add(label);
```

If it doesn't, you can use `javax.ImageIO.read(URL)` to load the chart image into a `BufferedImage` and then create a new `ImageIcon` to put that onto the label:

```
URL url = new URL(chart.toURLString());
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(url);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(bimg);

JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
tabbedPane.add(label);
```

Your application will need a live Internet connection for the chart image to show up. If you need the images to work when you have no Internet access, you'll have to use a different charting library such as [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).